# Java List with generics of Classes that implements an interface

Tags: java, list, generics

i have multiple classes that are very different between them , so i CAN'T extends all from one generic parent, beside Object

some of this classes implements an interface, called "Searchable" , others no

i have a class that extends ArrayList

```
public class ItemList<Object> extends ArrayList<Object>
```

and the generic Object for this list allow me to use this list for ALL my classes

now, for the only classes that implements that interface, i want to have an extension of ItemList , calling it "SearchList", that allow me to do some operations with method of the the interface
if one method of Searchable is "search(int x)" i want a method in "SearchList" like this

```
public int count(int x){
int ret=0;
       for(int i=0;i<this.size();i++{
            ret=ret+this.get(i).search(x);
        }
return ret;
}
```

how can i do something like this? becouse i know that i can't use generics

thanks for the help :)

Comment: `SomeClass<Object> extends ArrayList<Object>` is redundant imo

Comment: Please do not name your type parameter "Object"

Answer (score 0):

If *some* of your elements implement the `Searchable` interface, then you can test them using the `instanceof` operator.

```
for(Object o : this) {
    if(o instanceof Searchable) {
        Searchable s = (Searchable)o;

        // Do what you need to with it.
    }
}
```

***NOTE***: I wouldn't recommend extending `ArrayList` for this type of usage. Composition fits this a lot nicer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list containing only Searchable object, you can do :

```
public class SearchList<Searchable> extends ItemList<Object>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want `SearchList` to extend `ItemList`, but take only type arguments that extend `Searchable`?

```
public class SearchList<T extends Searchable> extends ItemList<T>
```